# Core Data entity with set

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, entity-relationship

I have a core data entity that contains many fields. One of them should contain a list of predefined colors. Later I would like to be able to apply a predicate on one or more of these color (like : find an object that have black and green color). My colors list'll be static.

How can I design my entity ? Should I have a Color entity with relationship ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I would recommend to create a *Color* entity and a to-many relationship `colors` from your *Entity* to *Color*.

If it is a static list of pre-defined colors, you can create the
color entities when the persistent store is created. Alternatively, you can "find or create" the color entities at application startup.

If the *Color* entity has a `name` attribute, you can find objects having a color with

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY colors.name = %@", @"red"];
```

To check for two colors, you can either use

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(ANY colors.name = %@) AND (ANY colors.name = %@)", @"black", @"green"];
```

or (I do hope that this is correct :-):

```
NSArray *colorNames = @[@"black", @"green"];
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(colors, $c, $c.name IN %@).@count >= 2", colorNames];
```

You can also (if required) add an `UIColor color` attribute to the *Color* entry, various 
strategies are described in "[Non-standard Persistent Attributes](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdNSAttributes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001919-SW1)" in the Core Data Programming Guide.